# hide an image for iphone screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Using media queries i am trying to hide a image of cube for desktop and then replace it with another iphone image for the cube....
i am able to hide the desktop image for iphone but the iphone image is not appearing.....
how to fix the issue.....

http://jsfiddle.net/QYvrt/27/

http://jsfiddle.net/QYvrt/27/embedded/result/

providing my code below

```
<div class="desktopContactImage" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png">desktopImage</div>

 <div class="iphoneContactImage" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/cubes/demoImage.png">iphoneImage</div>






@media (max-width: 767px) {

#rightSlider{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#rightSlider{
            display:none !important;
          }
#rightSlider{ 
            display:inherit !important;
          }

.desktopContactImage{

            display:none !important;
          }

.iphoneContactImage{
            display:inherit !important;
            border: 1px solid red;
          }



}

#slidenav{
            display:none !important;
          }
#slidenav{ 
            display:inherit !important;
          }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

#rightSlider{
    border: 1px solid green;
}


}






/* Demo styling */
#rightSlider{
        display: none;
      }
#slidenav{
        display: none;
      }



     .iphoneContactImage{
        display: none;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using display:inherit !important to unhide the element you may want to try

```
.iphoneContactImage{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If that doesn't work you can try some more techniques mentioned here: [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)